# jQuery Ajax not calling webmethod after url routing

Tags: c#, web-services, jquery, webmethod

my jquery ajax function is not calling webmethod. jquery function return webservice page's html.
function is not understand "ebulten_add" is a webmethod!

> "url:ajaxPage.aspx/e_bulten"

to write webmethod name or not write is same.. both of return ajaxPage.aspx html.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'ajaxPage.aspx/ebulten_Add',
                data: "{ebEmail:'" + Ebemail + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {

                    $("#span_result").hide();
                    $("#span_spinner").hide();
                    $("#span_result").html(result.d).fadeIn();
                },
                error: function (msg) {                     
                    $("#span_result").hide();
                    $("#span_spinner").hide();
                    $("#span_result").html("Lütfen tekrar deneyin.").fadeIn();
                }
            });`
```

web method in ajaxPage.aspx

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string ebulten_Add(string ebEmail)
{
    if (ebEmail == "Email")
    {
        return "*Bilgilerinizi Girmediniz";
    }
    else
    {
        List<ListItem> ebList = new List<ListItem>();           
        ebList.Add(new ListItem("@Eb_email", ebEmail));
        BL.Atom.GetByVoid("spEbulten_Add", ebList);
        return "*E-Bülten kaydınız başarıyla tamamlanmıştır";            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @SenadM. Either change the `dataType:text` or return JSON from your webmethod:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string ebulten_Add(string ebEmail)
{
    if (ebEmail == "Email")
    {
        return "{ \"response\": \"*Bilgilerinizi Girmediniz\"}";
    }
    else
    {
        List<ListItem> ebList = new List<ListItem>();           
        ebList.Add(new ListItem("@Eb_email", ebEmail));
        BL.Atom.GetByVoid("spEbulten_Add", ebList);
        return "{ \"response\": \"*E-Bülten kaydiniz basariyla tamamlanmistir\"}";            
    }
}
```

Also, make sure POST is enabled in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <!-- <add name="HttpGet"/> --> <!-- uncomment to enable get -->
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: code enter success function , but it still return ajaxPage html. webmethod does not work

Comment: Why is the method in `ajaxPage.aspx`? It should be a webservice: `ajaxPage.asmx`

Comment: yes i have ajaxPage.asmx too. but it is same to asmx.. i tried it for two page

Comment: Noticed one other thing: your data is not valid json, it should be: `data: '{ "ebEmail" : "' + Ebemail + '" }',`

Comment: Check out my update. Maybe POST is disabled (it is by default) in your `web.config`.

Comment: post and get are enable.. i try data: '{ "ebEmail" : "' + Ebemail + '" }',  it still return same html. is it because of url routing ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the HTML part. When you call it from a webservice, what HTML is being returned? `.asmx` doesn't have any HTML to begin with.

Comment: this error occured now..
System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: application/json; charset=utf-8. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Comment: Right, so check your `data`. Make sure its valid json.

Comment: it works. after i add these to webconfig.<system.webServer><handlers>. thanks Mrchif help me to define reason. 
<add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you are returning string not json

so just update your dataType: 'text' and it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

Just Change `var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings {AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent};` to `var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings {AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off};` This should solve the problem.